# A simple device to remotely alert someone

Tags: arduino, usb, device

We are developing a solution that can remotely alert someone around a relatively small area (around 300 meters).
Each user will carry a sort of pager. The server will send an alert to the device. The device will beep to warn the user of a specific event. The pager will display a very shot text.

Are you aware of an existing device on the market or a simple arduino-like solution.

My solution will be deployed on only one site, with 1 to 10 user.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately shopping questions are off-topic, as per the help centre.  If you have a specific electronics design issue you could edit your question.

Comment: Sounds like a cell phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give many details on requirements, restrictions, operating conditions (300m in open field, 300m through reinforced concrete walls, 300m through steel frame building...?).

I would think the easiest option these days is to use any messaging app for mobile phone, if you have data coverage it will not cost people anything and they all have a device already in their pockets. If coverage is an issue, throw a couple of wifi hotspots into the mix, again very cheap reliable existing technology.

You can fall back to SMS, there are companies that will do bulk SMS services with an internet gateway (EG e-mail or web form to sms) for very low cost.

If you need more standalone, PMR442 radios are cheap and many beep when they get a transmission, I don't know if there are versions which can accept data / messages.

Answer (score 0):

If the site is **covered by existing paging company**, some paging companies accept "user electronic input" where you can send them a '**email like' message** in specific format and they will put out the page for your on your group of subscribed pagers.

Or buy and install a Private paging system [Google search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=private%20pager%20system&safe=off) or if site already has good in door cellular phone coverage, an cell phone works too.

[One randomly selected example](http://www.rangetele.com/?page_id=108)

[Another example](http://www.zetron.com/en-us/products/paging.aspx)